# getting denied for svn update

Tags: svn, centos, commit

first i would like to say that everything was working perfectly. But i needed to update to php 5.2 so i did a yum update of my CentOS 5.5.

It went well and i got my php 5.2

But... When i tried to commit a file... I got this error

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: MERGE of '/xxxxxx': 200 OK
>   (http://www.xxxx.com)

You have to know that i have a post-commit that update the file to my webserver.. So I tried to remove the post-commit... and the commit worked.. So the problem is post-commit side

here my post-commit script

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
  execl("/usr/bin/svn", "svn", "update", "--username",
"xx.xxx", "--password", "xxx",
 "/var/www/vhosts/xx.com/subdomains/beta/httpdocs/",  (const
char *) NULL);
  return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

In the post-commit file there is just a call to that c program

When i try to run that c program manualy i get this error

> svn: Impossible d'ouvrir le
>   fichier
>   '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/subdomains/beta/httpdocs/.svn/tmp/entries':
>   Permission non accord?e

read as:  permission denied to open the file..

But why??? Why after i did the yum update my svn update is getting me that crapp permission denid???

Your help would appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: You can `ls -l /var/www/.../.svn/tmp/entries` to check if the directory was initially checked out by a different user, I guess it should be owned by your web server account.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A clean install of the repository helped :)